# why doesn't my @media queries work?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use `media queries` to change how my website looks at different sizes... Currently it doesn't work:

```css
html {background:#333;}
body {background:#F0F1F2;}
html, body {
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:'bl-reg', sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  color:#333;

  z-index:inherit;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, li, tr, th, td {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor:default;
}
a {
  font-family:'bl-reg', sans-serif;
  font-weight:inherit;
  font-size:inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:inherit;
  cursor:pointer;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
.margin-center {
  margin:auto auto;
}
.pull-left {
  float:left;
}
.pull-right {
  float:right;
}

div.navbar {
  height:48px;
  overflow:auto;
  background:#FFF;
}
div.navbar > ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}
div.navbar > ul li.brand,
div.navbar ul li.link {
  display:inline-block; 
}
div.navbar > ul li.brand {
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:14px;
}
div.navbar ul li.link {
  font-size:12px;
}
div.navbar > ul li a {
  display:block;
  padding:15px;
}
div.navbar > ul li.link a {
  display:block;
  padding:16.5px 15px;
  color:rgba(51,51,51,0.75);
}
div.navbar > ul li.link a:hover {
  color:rgba(51,51,51,1); 
}
div.navbar > ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 975px) {
  div.navbar > ul {
    width:975px;  
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 974px) {
  div.navbar > ul {
    width:100%;
  }
  div.navbar > ul > div.collapse {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:48px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fonts.css" />
    <script src="./jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./global.js"></script> 
  </head>

  <body style="display:none;">
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul class="margin-center">
        <li class="brand pull-left">
          <a href="#">stack</a>
        </li>
        <div class="collapse">
          <li class="link">
            <a href="#">Hello</a>
          </li>
          <li class="link">
            <a href="#">Hello</a>
          </li>
          <li class="link">
            <a href="#">Hello</a>
          </li>
          <li class="link pull-right">
            <a href="#">World</a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't opening the website with my browser width larger than `975px` force the `width` to `div.navbar > ul` and such. And then when it is smaller than `975px` force the `width`to `100%` and the other things within `max-width: 974px`

Comment: Please add relevant information, like the snippet of HTML that contains this navbar and the browser(s) you're testing with. Also, have you seen the 'Code snippet' button in the editor? Really helpful to try that!

Comment: @GolezTrol - Updated, and No - I haven't seen the code snippet button yet ^^; It seems to of only become popular on stackoverflow recently.

Comment: BTW: Your markup is wrong. A `ul` may only contain `li` not `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your that you declare that your using html 5 and have the meta tag for the viewport.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>jargin</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: hi, i've added the meta tag. It seems to allow the `position:absolute` and `margin-top` to work, but not the `width` ??

Answer (score 0):

are you using display:none in body? if you're using it mistakenly please remove that from your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are missing `<!DOCTYPE html>`

you are applying `display:none` in body, please remove it

**Media queries CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 974px) {

    html {
        background:yellow;
    }

}
```

**I have updated the fiddle(resize the window to take effect media queries)**

**http://jsfiddle.net/kbdvm5j6/12/**